# Calculate sum of selected radio values to animate a bar graph

Tags: jquery

I have a set of 5 questions with yes/no radio buttons. The no buttons have a value of 0 while the yes buttons have a value of 20 (representing 20%, so 5 x yes answers = 100%).

```
<div id="test-questions">
<p>Question 1
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="Set1" value="0" /><label for="r1"> No</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="Set1" value="20" /><label for="r2"> Yes</label>
</p>
<p>Question 2
  <input type="radio" id="r3" name="Set2" value="0" /><label for="r3"> No</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="r4" name="Set2" value="20" /><label for="r4"> Yes</label>
</p>
<p>Question 3
  <input type="radio" id="r5" name="Set3" value="0" /><label for="r5"> No</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="r6" name="Set3" value="20" /><label for="r6"> Yes</label>
</p>
<p>Question 4
  <input type="radio" id="r7" name="Set4" value="0" /><label for="r7"> No</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="r8" name="Set4" value="20" /><label for="r8"> Yes</label>
</p>
<p>Question 5
  <input type="radio" id="r9" name="Set5" value="0" /><label for="r9"> No</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="r10" name="Set5" value="20" /><label for="r10"> Yes</label>
</p>
<p><input id="total" type="hidden" name="total" value="" /></p>
</div>
```

I have the following script to calculate the total:

```
function setRadios(){
function sumRadios(){
    var total = 0, i = 1, oForm = this.form;
    while (radgrp = oForm.elements['Set' + (i++)]){
        j = radgrp.length;
        do
            if (radgrp[--j].checked){
                total += Number(radgrp[j].value);
                break;
            }
        while (j);
    }
    oForm.elements.total.value = total.toFixed(2);
}

var i = 0, input, inputs = document.getElementById('test-questions').getElementsByTagName('input');
while (input = inputs.item(i++))
    if (input.name.match(/^Set\d+$/))
        input.onclick = sumRadios;
}
onload = setRadios;
```

This all works correctly (although if you have a more elegant solution please feel free to say so) but what I want to do now is to change out a graphic based on what the total was, so if the total is '20' then display div1, if it's '40' display div2 and so on. The idea is to animate a bar graph ie 0%, 20%, 40%, 60% 80% or 100%.

I've never worked with jQuery before so be kind to me :)

Comment: maybe you want to use jqueryUI progressbar? - http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/ just set the value each time it changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an empty Div, with a background-color, and width 0, then change the with of that Div with the value of "total":

```
<div id="showbar" style="background-color:blue;height:1em;width:0;"></div>
```

In sumRadios():

```
document.getElementById('showbar').style.width = total+'px';
```

Comment: Thanks CoursesWeb, that's perfect.